# How can I identify view objects in a UIScrollView?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, tags

I have a `UIScrollView` with plenty of objects and I want to identify each of them. I currently do the following:

```
[learnLabel setTag:currentScrollElements];    
[learnStartButton setTag:currentScrollElements+10000];
[learnLike1Button setTag:currentScrollElements+20000];
[learnLike3Button setTag:currentScrollElements+30000];
[learnCommentField setTag:currentScrollElements+40000];
```

etc.

The ideal solution would be a system where I can assign the same number twice to two different objects (to a `UIButton` and a `UILabel`, for example). I do not want to run out of space, because the max value of tags is the same as the max value of an integer. How can I do this?

Comment: Your app will crash due to memory usage LONG before you run out of integer values.

Comment: `NSIntegerMax` is 2147483647. If you have 2 billion views, something tells me you have problems other than identifying them...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Theoretically, you can use tags without any problem, because it can be used with more views than the possible maximum capability of a device.

But it *will* be utterly **confusing** and **hard** to manage after you are dealing with lots of different views.

Your best bet is working with arrays or dictionaries, or better yet, redesign your view structure and use a `UITableView` or a `UICollectionView` with better memory management support built in.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can store all object in NSDictionary.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this.

```
#define LearnLabel          @"LearnLabel"
#define LearnStartButton    @"LearnStartButton"
#define LearnLike1Button    @"LearnLike1Button"
#define LearnLike3Button    @"LearnLike3Button"
#define LearnCommentField   @"LearnCommentField"
...
...
...


NSMutableDictionary* childObjectsDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[childObjectsDictionary setObject:learnLabel forKey:LearnLabel];
[childObjectsDictionary setObject:learnStartButton forKey:LearnStartButton];
[childObjectsDictionary setObject:learnLike1Button forKey:LearnLike1Button];
[childObjectsDictionary setObject:learnLike3Button forKey:LearnLike3Button];
[childObjectsDictionary setObject:learnCommentField forKey:LearnCommentField];
...
...
...
```